# Showing pivot table data joing two table using if conding

Tags: mysql

I am trying pivot table In MySQL.I have two tables One Is Master and another is details. first table contain...ID, Master_Code And Second table contain Id, master_id, Showroom_Name, Group_Code, Group_name, Party_Code. I am trying to show all add party code in a row belong to master code or Master ID. But my query didn't Give Me Proper Result

PHP 7, MySQL 5

```sql
SELECT add_party_code_masters.Master_Code,
       add_party_codes.showroom_name,
       add_party_codes.region,
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000822000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Settled',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000161000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Decora',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000221000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Power',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000213000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Pioneer',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000209000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Promising',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000321000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'TELL',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000202000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Prestige',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000204000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Popular',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000203000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Premium',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000201000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Prime',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000205000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Premio',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000381000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Exclusive',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000206000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Prominent',
       IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000207000', add_party_codes.party_code, '') AS 'Pride'
FROM add_party_code_masters
       JOIN add_party_codes
            ON add_party_code_masters.id = add_party_codes.master_id
```

Output Come:

```
    Master_Code showroom_name  Settled  Decora  Power
    1114001     Mayer_Doa      24434
    1114001     Mayer_Doa               25125
    1114001     Mayer_Doa                        25125
```

Desired Output:

```
     Master_Code showroom_name  Settled  Decora  Power
     1114001     Mayer_Doa      24434    25125   25125
```

Comment: Please share your data of table

Comment: Use MIN or MAX with IF i.e. MAX(IF(add_party_codes.group_code = 'R000822000', add_party_codes.party_code, '')) AS 'Settled' ............ and put all non aggregated column in group by it should give you expected output.